# Select and plot top frequencies with dplyr

Tags: r, select, ggplot2, count, dplyr

The objective is to select/filter top 3 (or n) events that have the largest frequencies (occurrences) in a dataframe then plot these using a barplot in ggplot2.

The example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  type=c("car","bike","horse","boat","yacht","train"),freq=c(20,2,5,60,11,10))
```

So far, I could arrange `df`:

```
df_order <- df %>% 
            arrange(desc(freq))
[1] df_order
type freq
1  boat   60
2   car   20
3 yacht   11
4 train   10
5 horse    5
6  bike    2
```

The desired result is to select only the top 3 `types` then plot these using a barplot. I think `count` will be useful, but not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After we order the dataset based on the 'freq' column (`arrange(...)`), we can the top 3 values with `slice`, use `ggplot`, specify the 'x' and 'y' variables in the `aes`, and plot the bar with `geom_bar`

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    arrange(desc(freq)) %>%
    slice(1:3) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x=type, y=freq))+
              geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Or another option is `top_n` which is a convenient wrapper that uses `filter` and `min_rank` to select the top 'n' (3) observations in 'freq' column and use `ggplot` as above.

```
top_n(df, n=3, freq) %>%
          ggplot(., aes(x=type, y=freq))+
              geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks akrun,  `top_n()` is a neat trick. I have to plot `df` as above with a similar `df2` using geom_grid() just to have 2 plots in 1 figure. Should I transform `type` to a factor?

Comment: @remi  Could you post that as a separate question?  It would be more clear in that way.

Comment: @remi I couldn't install the `library(gazetools)` which has the `geom_grid` as it says `‘gazetools’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)`

Comment: Hi akrun: back again with this question: how to force ggplot2 to plot the x-axis items non-alphabetically ordered but rather `freq` ordered?

Comment: @remi  Please post that as a separate question.