# Problem with visualizing top frequency Bar with desc() function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to visualize the ***top 3*** or ***n*** bars in R in an order one after another. I have followed [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141332/select-and-plot-top-frequencies-with-dplyr) on stack overflow in which he did exactly the same what I want. In my dataset, I don't have **y-axis** values where as `desc()` function requires one argument. I don't know what argument should I pass in this `desc()` function which can give me the **top 3** or ***n*** bars of a bar graph.

Mentioned below is my code and df. The first code for the bar graph works but not for the top 3 bars.

```
    values_1
1   C123
2   B323
3   C123
4   R333
5   R334
6   N123
7   U322
8   C123
9   U322
10  R444

Bars<- ggplot(df)+geom_bar(aes(x=values_1), bandwidth=0.5)+
ylab("Frequency")+xlab("My Values")
plot(Bars)
```

**Code For top 3 Bars**

```
df %>% 
    arrange(desc()) %>%
    slice(1:3) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=values_1))+
              geom_bar()
```

Error

```
Error in arrange()
dec() must be called with exactly one argument.
```

Comment: When using `desc()` you need to specify what variable you wish to arrange by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `count`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   count(values_1, sort = TRUE) %>% 
   slice_head(n = 3) %>%
   mutate(values_1 = factor(values_1, levels = unique(values_1))) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = values_1, y = n)) +
    geom_col() + 
    ylab("Frequency")+
    xlab("My Values")
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(values_1 = c("C123", "B323", "C123", "R333", "R334", 
"N123", "U322", "C123", "U322", "R444")), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Your first question was right as well but the bars were not in order. I have changed my question and you changed the answer as well :D